# How to take Snap shot of AGSMapView for ios?

Tags: ios, swift

```
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.AgsMapView.bounds.size,false, 0.0)
        self.view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        snapShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
```

He is my code, from above code getting blank image (white)

Comment: call "renderInContext" for "self.AgsMapView.layer" instead "self.view.layer".

Answer (score 0):

Try this code!!

```
    let layer = self.AgsMapView.layer
    let scale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.AgsMapView.frame.size, false, scale);
    layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let snapShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshot, nil, nil, nil)
```